# Mac alias/symbolic link question

Tags: macos, symbolic-link, alias

If I create a symbolic link or alias pointing to `$HOME/Desktop` and place it in a `.dmg` disk image, then distribute the dmg, will the link still point to the Desktop for the end user?

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this?

Comment: @Barjavel I ended up creating installer and generating the link with postflight script as geekosaur suggested bellow in comments. As long as I remember it didn't work out with just copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since the environment variable will be replaced when the link is created. Using `~` will not work either, for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. I am hopelessly trying to solve the problem described in my following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505442/how-to-set-up-packagemaker-to-create-an-icon-on-desktop-after-installation Maybe you have some idea how could I create a link to an application on desktop after installation?

Comment: Nope. I don't actually know anything about the high-level Mac stuff, sorry.

Comment: Per this [Package Maker HOWTO](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/PackageMaker_Howto.html), you can use a `postinstall` or `postflight` script.